# Unity: How to only render part of an object which is above a plane?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering, effect

There is a plane and a cube.
If the cube is totally above the plane, then it will be totally displayed (rendered).
If the cube is half above the plane and half bellow the plane, then only the upper half will be display, and the part which is bellow the plane will not be display (transparent).
If the cube is totally bellow the plane, then it will totally not be displayed.
In a word, render only the part of the cube which is above the plane, as the cube moving down, more part will be hidden (will not be displayed).

I am a neophyte of unity and I am still struggling with this problem. Could Anyone help me to solve this problem (detailed steps and logic)?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? To some level it sounds like yourr looking for occlusion but the question doesnt sound enough like it.

Comment: What you describe is literally the default behavior using the built-in default material/shader ... What exactly have you tried? What is the issue? In short: basically use any shader that uses the zBuffer (basically = occlusion by distance)